# Django-taggit how to get all tags

Tags: django, django-taggit

I can get all tags' name one by one like this in template

```
{% for tag in blog.tags.all %}
    <span class="label label-default">{{ tag.name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

And I can get a input from a form like this `{{ form.tags }}` and it gives me:

```
<input id="id_tags" name="tags" type="text" value="xxx,y y y,zzz">
```

However I want to customize my input in my template like this

```
<input id="id_tags" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="title" type="text" placeholder="tags" value="{{ form.tags }}">
```

How to set the input's value="`{{ form.tags }}`"?

Comment: Can you kindly update your question with your form class? You would probably need to populate your "tags" field with an initial value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your model you can do the following:

1. First you should have

   tags = TaggableManager(blank = True)
2. the following will get all the tags and you can use get_tags in a list_field to get all tags for each record.

   `def get_tags(self):
   tags = []
   for tag in self.tags.all():
   tags.append(str(tag))
   return ', '.join(tags)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you'd be better off either using Django's class-based forms (rather than hand-coding the HTML) iff possible, as Taggit already handles this for you.

But to try to answer your question, if you want to get all the tags for a particular object, I think what you need is `blog.tags.values_list('name', flat = True)`, which means you'll need either to write a custom template tag or - if you're using the word 'blog' to mean 'blog *post*' and you're on a single blog post page - you could add the above to the view's context.